# Xamarin's WebView Scrolling Acts Strange on Certain Devices

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

In recent months, I've been developing a Mobile App on Android using Xamarin and MvvmCross.

There is a current issue I've been trying to seek out without any luck.

It's a WebView with some javascript injected. On some devices when you start scrolling a nested list it will also scroll the entire page.

I've changed the website to include the overscroll-y on the elements for the list.

Here are some video examples. If someone could give some insight on why this is happening.

- MOTO6: https://youtu.be/-DGOXW2lYOs
- Lenovo:
  https://youtu.be/ZuxUm1olTpY

Comment: Do you try to build your project at Android emulator? it works fine or not?

Comment: When I created an emulator with Android version 9.0 Nexus, it exerts the same problem as the MOTO6.